# Замена input value на вводимое значение

Tags: javascript

- в поле `<input>` "дата сдачи..." при первом клике на него в `value=""` вставляется текущее значение даты + 3 дня (default);
- если пользователь хочет изменить значение по default он вводит его с клавиатуры и оно изменяется;

В моем примере, если ввести значение 1 раз,перейти на другое поле input,а потом попытаться изменить это значение ещё раз, ничего не получается,почему, как это сделать лучше?

```js
function formatDate(date) {

  var dd = date.getDate() + 3;
  if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;

  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

  var yy = date.getFullYear();
  if (yy < 10) yy = '0' + yy;

  return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yy;
}

var d = new Date();

dat.addEventListener('click', dateplace)

function dateplace() {

  dat.setAttribute('placeholder', formatDate(d))
  dat.value = formatDate(d);
}

dat.addEventListener('keydown', dateval)

function dateval() {
  dat.value = '';
  dat.removeEventListener('keydown', dateval)
}
```

```html
<label class="g">
  <span id="vsp" class="invalid hide"></span>
  <input id="special" class="mail" type="text" name="a_subject" autocomplete=none value="" placeholder="специальность...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <input id="a_subject" class="mail" type="text" name="a_subject" autocomplete=none value="" placeholder="предмет...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required>
  <input  type="text" id="dat" placeholder="дата сдачи..." onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10">
</label>
```

Comment: Что работает только 1 раз?

Comment: @Igor что описано в первых двух пунктах

Comment: @Igor  Если ввести дату один раз, с клавиатуры, то потом это не работает , если только не выделить значение вручную, т.е его не получиться изменить

Comment: Не понимаю. У меня значение становится 09/01/2020 каждый раз, когда я щелкаю по инпуту. Браузер Chrome.

Comment: @igor ну вот, теперь если менять его, то оно измениться, но если фокуснуть другой input , затем вернуться обратно, то его уже не поменять